# Clear site browser cache in php

Tags: php

trying to Clear browser site cache in php,

for firefox browser is working fine, as we want but when i run in chrome it didnt work.
see code,

---

```
 header('Clear-Site-Data: "cache", "cookies", "storage", "executionContexts"'); //Firefox
 
 // Crome
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
 header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
 header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  
 header ("Pragma: no-cache");
 header('Clear-Site-Data: "cookies"');
                
 return $this->getSuccessResponse("Token Valid");
```

Comment: Have you tried PHP's built-in function `clearstatcache`

Comment: @NaveedRamzan [clearstatcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) does _not_ clear the browser cache, it clears cached file information on the _server_

Comment: Not sure why you're sending the `Clear-Site-Data` header twice. The second one would overwrite the first one (unless you provide the 2nd parameter as false). [header method  docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Also note the [Clear-Site-Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data) compatibility table. I think only cookies and storage can be cleared in most browsers

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't clear cache from browser perfectly, one only option is you can do manually. There is some code. I hope it will work.

```
<?php 
  header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
  header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```